# HHVM should not write to syslog and messages

Tags: debian, hhvm

I've a problem with hhvm, because it's writing errors to 3 different logfiles:

- /var/log/hhvm/error.log
- /var/log/syslog
- /var/log/messages

I only want it to write the messages to the first logfile.
I've set `hhvm.log.use_syslog = 0`, but this does not help.

How can I keep hhvm from writing to syslog and messages?
(using debian linux)

Answer (score 0):

Debian uses rsyslog by default, so check your /etc/rsyslog.conf. You'll likely see entries in there that set those destinations. You'll also need to look for hhvm as a source, and make sure that the source has only the destination that you want.